# Using JComboBox - why does getSelectedItem() work and Java objects?

Tags: java, swing, object, casting, parseint

I have a combo box like this:

```
static final String[] intString = {"Dist.","4","5","6","7","8"};
static JComboBox numList = numList = new JComboBox(intString);
```

And I need to grab which item is selected and convert it to type int.
I used this:

```
Integer.parseInt(numList.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

But honestly do not understand why it works. If I do not include "toString()," the associated error is:

```
parseInt(string) in Integer cannot be applied to Object
```

So, I passed a String and the items in the list are now objects? I understand that when you have a class and instantiate it, you are effectively creating a reference to an object with all the associated methods and instance variables of the class. But I do not understand object creations, when and why, beyond this concept.

Why are the items in a list now objects, and how can you cast an object to a String?
I understand that you can pass subclasses when superclasses are referenced:

```
ArrayList<Object> dogList = new ArrayList<Object>();
Dog yorkie = new Dog(); 
dogList.add(yorkie); //since Dog extends object
Dog doberman = (Dog) dogList[0]; //re-cast to original type
```

Perhaps the concept is similar.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<>()` ?

Comment: `String` is just another `Object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Integer.parseInt(numList.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

The getSelectItem() method returns an Object. You get the error messeage (when you don't use the toString() method) because the parseInt() method is expecting a String.

> So, I passed a String and the items in the list are now objects?

The Object still is a String, so you could do it this way:

```
Object selected = numList.getSelectedItem();
String selectedString = (String)selected;
Integer.parseInt( selectedString );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and override the `toString():String` method in the `Dog` class.

If you don't have a `toString()` defined in your custom class, then it may return a pointer to memory for that Object.

Answer (score 2):

`getSelectedItem` will return a type of `Object`, which is, obviously, not compatible with the expectations of `Interger.parseInt(String)`.

All classes extend from `Object`, so everything can be passed and used where `Object` is expected.  It is the lowest common denominator.

One of the methods of `Object` is the `toString` method.  `String#toString` simple returns itself.

For example.  You are a `Human`, you are also known as `sherrellbc` (and presumably other names).  So, if I had a method took `Human` as parameter, I could pass you to it, because you can be cast and treated as a `Human`.